# Unable to include emojis in Crashlytics Beta release notes through fastlane

Tags: ios, crashlytics, fastlane, crashlytics-beta

I noticed that Fastlane/Crashlytics script is unable to use emoji characters in the release notes file.

Using something like  will appear ???? on the published release note.

```
 crashlytics(
      api_token: "xxx",
      build_secret: "xxx",
       notes: File.read("../ChangeLog.txt"),
       groups: ["xxx"]
   )
```

The file "ChangeLog.txt" is a unicode(UTF-8) saved file and holds the data correctly.

Using of emojis works when release notes are manually submitted through Crashlytics Beta dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried `File.binread()` for `notes`?

Comment: I tried it but the issue still exists.

Comment: Best create an issue at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues then

Comment: Thanks for the link. will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Crashlytics team and it appears to be a bug on Crashlytics Beta upload module.

The bug is there but since it's not reported by many developers, not a high priority to fix. I'll update my answer if i get any new feedbacks.